# ApiModelProperty annotation of Swagger is not working on Map

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger-ui

I am using Swagger(version 3.0.0) with spring boot(2.5.14). I have an unreachable model class named SampleModel that I have added to swagger using the Docket object

```
    @Bean
    public Docket api(TypeResolver typeResolver) {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build()
                .additionalModels(typeResolver.resolve(SampleModel.class));
    }
```

SampleModel.java

```
@Getter
@Setter
@ApiModel
public class SampleModel {
    @ApiModelProperty(value="student id")
    String id;
    String name;
    Integer age;
    Object address;
    @ApiModelProperty(value="I need to add some description here",reference = "Foo.java")
    public HashMap<String, Object> mapObj;
}
```

This class appears on the UI under Models, but the metadata for mapObj does not appear.

The value added to **id** reflects though.

Can someone help me add properties/metadata to a Map please